# iOS login with facebook not returning email even parameter and permission given

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have read all related post on stackoverflow for this problem but nothing works.

I Tried to login with facebook and its works fine but it not returning email address.

Here is my FBSDKGraphRequest code

```
let request = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath:"me", parameters: ["fields":"email,first_name,gender"]);

    request.startWithCompletionHandler { (connection : FBSDKGraphRequestConnection!, result : AnyObject!, error : NSError!) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            print("The information requested is : \(result)")
        } else {
            print("Error getting information \(error)");
        }
    }
```

Which shows in console

```
The information requested is : {
    "first_name" = MyName;
     gender = male;
     id = 252013518608849;
 }
```

My login button code is

```
let loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton = {
    let button = FBSDKLoginButton()
    button.readPermissions = ["email"];
    return button
}()
```

And i add this button in viewdidload 
   `view.addSubview(loginButton)`

I don't know why it is not returning email.

Comment: Does the user have a _verified_ e-mail address in their profile?

Comment: Thanks CBroe....its working now

Answer (score 0):

Plese write below code on button action on which clicked you want to open facebook.

```
    let login = FBSDKLoginManager()
    login .logInWithReadPermissions(["public_profile", "email", "user_friends","user_birthday","user_friends","user_education_history","user_hometown"], fromViewController: self) { (result, error) -> Void in


        if !(error == nil)
        {
            NSLog("Process error");
        }
        else if result.isCancelled
        {
            NSLog("Cancelled")
            FBSDKLoginManager().logOut()
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog("Logged in");
            let fbloginresult : FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult = result
            if(fbloginresult.grantedPermissions.contains("email"))
            {
                self.returnUserData()
                //fbLoginManager.logOut()
            }

        }
    }

    FBSDKLoginManager().logOut()
```

It will work fine for you.Provide your feed back.Happy coding.

Comment: what us self.returnUserData()?

Comment: self.returnUserdata() is functionname inwhich below code is written.

let request = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath:"me", parameters: ["fields":"email,first_name,gender"]);

    request.startWithCompletionHandler { (connection : FBSDKGraphRequestConnection!, result : AnyObject!, error : NSError!) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            print("The information requested is : \(result)")
        } else {
            print("Error getting information \(error)");
        }
    }

Comment: No still it not returning email id

Comment: okkk now write this code where self.returnUserData is written.
 if((FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken()) != nil){
            FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields": "id, name, first_name, birthday,hometown,friends,gender,last_name, picture.type(large), email,cover"]).startWithCompletionHandler({ (connection, result, error) -> Void in
                
                if (error == nil){
                    
                    print(result)
                    
                    
                    


                    
            }
        }
            )
        }

Comment: It return birthdate, first_name, friends, gender, id, last_name, name, picture but not email address

Comment: is it going on this condition
    if(fbloginresult.grantedPermissions.contains("email"))
                {
                    self.returnUserData()
                    
                   
                }

Comment: Mark my answer positive if it help you

Comment: Yes it is going on this condition but why result containing email?

Comment: is it going on this condition if(fbloginresult.grantedPermissions.contains("email")) { 
self.returnUserData() 
}

Comment: yes it is going...if it not going there then how returnUserData called?

Comment: Means it contains email id

Comment: No it means permission has email...but returned result not contain email

Comment: @Divyesh : Please check your app developer account and make sure you made your app public or not
is your app is live or not and make sure in approved item email is showing green or not

Comment: where i can check that? i can't find any option for public and private in facebook developer

Comment: go your developer account  then go app review option  then make your app live .

Comment: still not getting email

Comment: ab tumse naa ho payega bhai.

Comment: why? i don't know what is problem. even i given permission for email

Comment: @Divyesh : Now may be you are login with mobile number Plz check with another acoount with email id.